# Extract (stream-like) compressed wordlist directly to shell, line by line

Tags: shell, compression, dictionary-attack, word-list

I want to extract a huge wordlist and use its contents like a "stream" to the shell.

This would permit one to perform dictionary attacks without having to decompress the entire wordlist.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit more searching, and I've just found this [here](https://pseudoscripter.wordpress.com/2011/03/25/writing-7zcat-works-like-zcat-on-7z-files/):

```
7z e -so -bd "$@" 2>/dev/null compressed_file.7z | tail
```

This would print the last 10 lines of the compressed file without having to extract or store it, sending all errors to `/dev/null`. This is just what I needed!